# Changing lookup parameters for Django object query

Tags: python, django, django-models

Two of the models in my Django project are

```
class ContractPlans(models.Model):
  cp_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, db_column = "ContractPlanId", max_length = 100L)
  parentorg = models.ForeignKey("Parentorgs")
  contractnum = models.ForeignKey("Contracts", db_column = "ContractNum")
  plan_id = models.CharField(max_length = 100L, db_column = "PlanID")
  eff_date = models.DateField()
  exp_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  planname = models.CharField(max_length=100L, db_column='PlanName') 


class ContractPlanTags(models.Model):
  contract_plan_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True, db_column = "table_id")
  parentorg = models.ForeignKey("Parentorgs", db_column = "parentorg_id")
  contractnum = models.ForeignKey("Contracts", db_column = "ContractNum")
  planid = models.ForeignKey("ContractPlans", db_column = "PlanId")
  tag_id = models.IntegerField()
  tag_value_id = models.ForeignKey("Tags", db_column = "tag_value_id")
  eff_date = models.DateField()
  exp_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm executing a `prefetch_related()` query on `ContractPlanTags` by

```
lst = ContractPlanTags.objects.prefetch_related().filter(parentorg = request.REQUEST["parentorg"])
```

This is intended to get all the foreign key objects associated with this model class in one database hit.

My issue is that Django keeps throwing an error

```
DoesNotExist: ContractPlans matching query does not exist. 
Lookup parameters were {'cp_id__exact': u'805'}
```

What I want to do is pull the value associated with `ContractPlans.plan_id` and `ContractPlans.planname` inside a serializer loop to pass to the view as a JSON object.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: do you have a record in the database for `ContractPlans` with id 805 ?

Comment: Note that `prefetch_related` doesn't actually avoid multiple database queries.  `select_related` does, and might be more appropriate here.  You'll still get exceptions if your database has broken foreign keys, though.

Answer (score 0):

when you filter on a `foreign key`, you need to pass an object of that foreign model:

```
parent_org = get_object_or_404(Parentorgs, pk=request.REQUEST["parentorg"])
lst = ContractPlanTags.objects.prefetch_related().filter(parentorg = parent_org)
```

Comment: I think the error is in another part then. It literally says you're trying to pull ContractPlan with id 805 from the database, however it doesn't exist. Could you check if it exists for me?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what's wrong:

```
DoesNotExist: ContractPlans matching query does not exist. 
Lookup parameters were {'cp_id__exact': u'805'}
```

One of your `ContractPlanTags` objects has an invalid foreign key. You need to fix that by either setting the key to `None` or creating the missing `ContractPlans` object with a `cp_id` of 805.

You should also enforce your database integrity properly, to prevent it happening in the future.